# AS3 MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE event stops responding after MouseEvent.CLICK call

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, event-handling, mouseevent

I have several stage event handlers to enable mouseovers over several dynamically generated moviecilps on the stage that then change their alpha to indicate the mouse is over that particular mc... fairly trivial (mcOver handler). Additionally, I also want to know what MC is clicked, so I update a public variable (public var activemc:Number) with the ID of the dynamic movieclip when the mouse is over it (using a hitTest to check, which is why the EventListener is added to stage and not to the MC), which is checked in the mcClicked handler:

This is in the constructor:

```
//stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startDrawing);
   //stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopDrawing);
   stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mcOver);
   //stage.addEventListener(Event.MOUSE_LEAVE, outlinesHide);
   stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, mcClicked);
```

However, the mouseover behaviour (alpha 0 when over, alpha 1 when out) stops working as soon as I click on any movieclip on the stage, and the mcClicked ID checking (below) stops working completely. I don't know if this is to do with focus:

```
private function mcClicked(event:MouseEvent):void {

myTextField.text = String(activemc); // activemc is a public var:Number with the movieclip //ID

}
```

I then tried adding the event handler for the stage mouse_move again and this gets the mouseover working again but only for 1 more click, after which it stops again:

```
private function mcClicked(event:MouseEvent):void {

myTextField.text = String(activemc); // activemc is a public var:Number with the movieclip //ID


stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mcOver);
}
```

I'd be extremely grateful if anyone could help sort out this really annoying behaviour! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just a try, instead of alpha 0, try alpha = 0.1 or greater on mouseover.

Another try worth giving, stop the propagation of MouseEvent in "mcClicked" - this is to check if anywhere else the mouse move is being removed from stage.

Comment: Just before I trouble you further, I think I may have found the problem. I will update you shortly.

edit: I solved it

Comment: edit: I solved it - it was a case of myTextField.text being updated with the activemc value BUT ALSO in the mcOver event handler to check the total number of mcs on stage. Thus if I cliked on MC3 then the mouseover behaviour would only work for movieclips 1 and 2. It was simply a case of being lazy and updating a shared textField! Thanks for helping.